# The Cross Ratio of a Mobius Transformation - Definition Clarification

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

so the Mobius transformation $f(z)$ of an extended complex plane preserves the following cross ratio
$$\frac{(w_1-w_4)(w_3-w_2)}{(w_1-w_2)(w_3-w_4)}=\frac{(z_1-z_4)(z_3-z_2)}{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}$$
where $w_i$ and $z_i$ belongs to the extended complex plane. I have a silly question about the numeration. Let's say I want to recover that cross ratio in a couple of years, and I will know that I need to put $$(a-b)(c-d)$$ on the top. But, what goes on the bottom $$(a-c)(b-d)\text{ or }(a-d)(b-c)\text{ and two more options. }$$
So, to answer that question, I consider all 4 cases and simply did the renumerations. So, I got that the choice does not matter as I always will obtain the desired
$$\frac{(z_1-z_4)(z_3-z_2)}{(z_1-z_2)(z_3-z_4)}.$$
Is there a shorter way to argue that? Or, is there another intuition that stands behind that definition?

Comment: Which denominator is morally "right" I guess depends on where you got the cross-ratio from, how you want to use it, or simply convention. But one thing I don't understand is why you think there are "two more options" - there aren't, are there? There are only three ways to group four variables into two pairs, so there can only be two options for the denominator (not counting swapping the order of subtractions).

Answer (score 1):

The cross-ratio – as I learned it many years ago – is defined as
$$
 (z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = T(z_1)
$$
where $T$ is the (unique) Möbius transformation which maps $(z_2, z_3, z_4)$ to $(1, 0, \infty)$, in that order. This definition holds for all $z_k$ in the extended complex plane, and it easy to remember.

For finite values $z_k$ that is
$$
(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) = \frac{(z_1 −z_3)(z_2 −z_4)}{(z_1 − z_4)(z_2 − z_3)}
$$
which coincides with the definition given in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio).

One could also map $(z_2, z_3, z_4)$ to any other permutation of $(1, 0, \infty)$, that gives [$6$ possible definitions of the cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio#Six_cross-ratios). I assume that the actual definition is just by convention. The important properties (it is invariant under Möbius transformations, and it is a real number exactly if the four points line on a circle or a line) are not affected by that choice.